# PostgreSQL query using posgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to execute this query in pgAdmin 4 however I am running into errors every time I try to run it. Please see the code and error below:

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;

--
-- Name: routing; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE SCHEMA routing;


SET search_path = routing, pg_catalog;

SET default_with_oids = true;

--
-- Name: edges; Type: TABLE; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE edges (
    edge_id integer NOT NULL,
    vertex_id1 integer,
    vertex_id2 integer,
    level1 integer,
    level2 integer,
    type character varying(20),
    door character varying(20),
    door_rev character varying(20),
    network character varying(20),
    length double precision,
    x1 double precision,
    y1 double precision,
    x2 double precision,
    y2 double precision,
    the_geom public.geometry,
    CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK ((st_ndims(the_geom) = 2)),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK (((geometrytype(the_geom) = 'LINESTRING'::text) OR (the_geom IS NULL))),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK ((st_srid(the_geom) = 900913))
);


--
-- Name: vertices; Type: TABLE; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE vertices (
    vertex_id integer NOT NULL,
    level integer,
    the_geom geometry,
    CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK ((st_ndims(the_geom) = 2)),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK (((geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POINT'::text) OR (the_geom IS NULL))),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK ((st_srid(the_geom) = 900913))
);


--
-- Name: edges_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY edges
    ADD CONSTRAINT edges_pkey PRIMARY KEY (edge_id);


--
-- Name: vertices_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY vertices
    ADD CONSTRAINT vertices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (vertex_id);


--
-- Name: edges_the_geom_1335166950969; Type: INDEX; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

CREATE INDEX edges_the_geom_1335166950969 ON edges USING gist (the_geom);


--
-- Name: edges_vertex_id1_1335166950797; Type: INDEX; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

CREATE INDEX edges_vertex_id1_1335166950797 ON edges USING btree (vertex_id1);


--
-- Name: edges_vertex_id2_1335166950907; Type: INDEX; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

CREATE INDEX edges_vertex_id2_1335166950907 ON edges USING btree (vertex_id2);


--
-- Name: vertices_the_geom_1335166951469; Type: INDEX; Schema: routing; Owner: -
--

CREATE INDEX vertices_the_geom_1335166951469 ON vertices USING gist (the_geom);
```

A bit of background:
I have the following extensions

- pgrouting
- plpgsql
- postgis
- postgis_topology
- fuzzystrmatch

Am running version PostgreSQL 10.3 on x86_64

I get the following output message:

```
ERROR:  function st_ndims(public.geometry) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong here? The original function was `CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK ((public.ndims(the_geom) = 2)),` however when reading up on this PostgreSQL 10.3 no longer supports ndims and has now switched to st_ndims. However when I changed it, it still isn't being recognised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have removed `public` from your search path, so nothing in this schema will be found.

try

```
SET search_path = public, routing, pg_catalog;
```

Comment: Ok I added it in the wrong place! When I added it after the CREATE SCHEMA routing; it worked! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip.
I faced the problem because **pg_dump** with the -a extension adds the following statement by default, erasing the search_path

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;    
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;
```

I had to disable it to add the data